# Bash IO redirection, open & close 'fd', can someone explain?

Tags: bash, io

I try to understand this concept for years, with at this time some incomplete knowledge of this.

Is anyone here can make a kind of a tutorial or good explanations with examples on how to

- open a new `fd`
- read from `fd`
- use `fd`
- close `fd`

I have read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html and `man bash`, but it's not clear, there's no concrete and understandable examples at all.

If someone can explain it well, will be a valuable answer, not only for me. The syntax is most of the time a bit obfuscated.
Sometimes that require `exec`, sometimes not.

Comment: [I/O Redirection in Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

Comment: Not very good resource, but thanks @choroba

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some translations for Bourne-like shells:

| system call | shell interface | shells | comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `open("file", O_RDONLY)` | `exec 3< file` | all | here open on fd 3¹ |
| `open("file", O_RDONLY)` | `exec {fd}< file` | zsh ksh93 bash | fd returned in `$fd`² |
| `open("file", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC|O_CREAT)` | `exec 3> file` | all | ³ |
| `open("file", O_WRONLY|O_APPEND|O_CREAT)` | `exec 3>> file` | all | <sup>4</sup> |
| `open("file", O_RDWR|O_CREAT)` | `exec 3<> file` | all |  |
| `open("file", ...)` | `sysopen ...` | zsh | in zsh/system module |
| `dup2(4, 5)` | `exec 5>&4` | all | same as `exec 5<&4` |
| `dup(4)` | `exec {fd}>&4` | zsh ksh93 bash | fd returned in `$fd` |
| `write(4, data, length)` | `print -rnu4 -- "$data"` | ksh zsh | bash has an example loadable `print` builtin as well<sup>5</sup> |
| `write(...)` | `syswrite ...` | zsh | in zsh/system module |
| `read(4, var...)` | `sysread -i 4 ... var` | zsh | in `zsh/system` module |
| `read(4, var...)` | `IFS= read -ru4 ... var` | ksh zsh bash | reads a line. Beware of limitations.<sup>5</sup> |
| `close(4)` | `exec 4>&-` | all | or `exec 4<&-` |
| `lseek(4, 123, SEEK_SET)` | `exec 4>#((123))` | ksh93 |  |
| `lseek(4, 123, SEEK_CUR)` | `exec 4>#((CUR + 123))` | ksh93 |  |
| `lseek(4, 123, SEEK_END)` | `exec 4>#((EOF + 123))` | ksh93 |  |
| `lseek(...)` | `sysseek ...` | zsh | in zsh/system module<sup>6</sup> |
| `pipe()` | `exec 4>>|5` | yash | fd 4 the writing end, 5 the reading end |
| `fstat(4, var)` | `zstat -f 4 -H var` | zsh | in zsh/stat module |
| `select(...)` | `zselect ...` | zsh | in zsh/zselect module |

zsh also has some `zsh/net/socket`, `zsh/net/tcp`, `zsh/zpty` modules to create an manipulate other sorts of fds.

Using `exec` changes the file descriptors of the shell process. Most of the times however, you only want to change file descriptors of some other command, like `ls -l dir/ > file` (short for `ls -l dir/ 1> file`) to open `file` on fd 1 (stdout) for `ls` only, or a section of code:

```
{
  echo Some Header
  ls -l dir/
} 1> file 2>> error.log
```

`foo | bar` does a `pipe()`<sup>7</sup> followed by some `dup2()`s or  equivalent and `close()`s in concurrent processes so fd 1 of the process that will run `foo` goes to the writing end of the pipe and fd 0 or `bar` goes to the reading end. Other shell constructs that use or may use pipes include command substitution (`var=$(cmd)`, `` var=`cmd` ``), Korn-like shell process substitution (`foo <(bar) >(baz)`), co-processes, yash's process redirection.

---

<sup>¹ in ksh93 and bash, if `file` is `/dev/tcp|udp/host/port`, it doesn't do a real open but creates a network socket instead.</sup>

<sup>² Same can be done for the other `>`, `>>`, `<>`, `>`  operators</sup>

<sup>³ If the `noclobber` option is on, a `O_EXCL` is added if the destination is a regular file, which can be bypassed with the `>|` or `>!` operators depending on the shell</sup>

<sup><sup>4</sup> In the Bourne shell, there was no `O_APPEND`, but the shell seeked to the end after open</sup>

<sup><sup>5</sup> In other shells, you can always do `printf %s "$var" >&4`. That doesn't write to fd 4, but writes to fd 1, after a temporary `dup2(4, 1)` which in effect achieves the same goal. Same for `IFS= read -r line <&4`.</sup>

<sup><sup>6</sup> See also the `systell(fd)` math function to return a fd's position which is another interface to `lseek()`</sup>

<sup><sup>7</sup> Except with ksh93 on some systems that uses `socketpair()`s instead of pipes. Same goes for some other constructs that use pipes.</sup>

Comment: I wonder if it is asking too much, but, that should be very great to have another column in your table that describe the behavior of the row (open, copy, close...) to people not knowing what are the syscalls in C.